# Higher moments of Vector Auto-Regressive (VAR) process

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, stationarity, vector-autoregression

If we have a VAR process:

$\begin{align} 
\mathbf{y}_t = A_1\mathbf{y}_{t-1} + \dots + A_d\mathbf{y}_{t-d} + \boldsymbol{\epsilon}_t, \quad t \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}$

With the stability condition met:

$\det(I - A_1z - \dots - A_d z^d) \neq 0$ for $|z| \leq 1$

We know that the second moments exist, that is we can compute the covariance matrix.

I was know wondering if it is possible to estimate higher moments.
In particular, I want to be able to show that the $2 + 2\epsilon$ moment, for $\epsilon \in (0,1]$ is bounded.

More precisely, find a constant $M$ s.t

$\mathbb{E}[|y_{it}|^{2 + 2 \epsilon}] \leq M, \quad \forall \; 1 \leq i \leq p$ for some $\epsilon \in (0,1]$

Comment: somehow related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559971/is-the-third-moment-of-an-ar1-dependent-on-t/560013#560013